# WinSock getaddrinfo to get IP from hostname fails until ipconfig /flushdns is called

Tags: winapi, dns, ping, winsock, getaddrinfo

Getting an IP address from a hostname is normally done by calling `getaddrinfo` (which is really just an alias for `WspiapiGetAddrInfo`).

We see cases where this fails.   At that same time as the failure:

- `ping {hostname}` is able to resolve the hostname just fine.
- `ping -4 {hostname}` also fails to resolve the hostname, just like `getaddrinfo`.

The solution to fix the `getaddrinfo` and the `ping -4` failure situation is to run

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

The above seems to indicate that `ping -4` and `getaddrinfo` are resolving the address using an (apparently bad) entry in an internal DNS cache.

Is there a way to programmatically clear that cache (doing whatever `ipconfig /flushdns` does), or better, have `getaddrinfo` not use the cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to programmatically clear that cache (doing whatever
>   ipconfig /flushdns does)

`ipconfig /flushdns` does this:

```c
typedef BOOL(WINAPI *DFRC)();
DFRC DnsFlushResolverCache;
HMODULE hDll = LoadLibrary(L"DnsApi.dll");
DnsFlushResolverCache = (DFRC)GetProcAddress(hDll, "DnsFlushResolverCache");
BOOL bRet = DnsFlushResolverCache();
// code...
FreeLibrary(hDll);
```

Comment: @DougN Just note that typical networking applications do not need to flush the cache manually. You need to find out why your cache is getting corrupted and fix that issue instead.

Comment: I would love to know why it's getting corrupted but that is somewhere deep in Windows.   We've seen it at a few client sites so it's not isolated to just a single computer.   If  you have any ideas on how to diagnose I am open to any suggestions.